# Transpose Column to Rows Where Values Are Similar

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a column where data is stacked. Within this data, there are values which are similar to one another I am wondering if there is a way to transpose based on on their similarities.

Here's an example of how the data looks.

```
    +---+------------------+
    |   |       A          |  
    +---+------------------+
    | 1 | st.south.23.001  |  
    +---+------------------+
    | 2 | st.south.23.002  |   
    +---+------------------+
    | 3 | st.south.23.003  |  
    +---+------------------+
    | 4 | nt.north.35.001  |
    +---+------------------+
    | 5 | nt.north.35.003  |  
    +---+------------------+
    | 6 | nt.north.35.004  |
    +---+------------------+
    | 7 | st.south.29.001  |  
    +---+------------------+
    | 8 | st.south.29.002  |
    +---+------------------+
    | 9 | st.south.29.003  |  
    +---+------------------+
    | 10| st.south.29.005  |
    +---+------------------+
```

Here's how the desired result would look like. I wasn't able to fit all of the entries q.q .

```
    +---+------------------+-----------------+------------------+
    |   |        A         |        B        |         C        |
    +---+------------------+-----------------+------------------+
    | 1 | st.south.23.001  | st.south.23.002 |  st.south.23.003 | 
    +---+------------------+-----------------+------------------+
    | 2 | nt.north.35.001  | nt.north.35.003 | nt.north.35.004  |
    +---+------------------+-----------------+------------------+
    | 3 | st.south.29.001  | st.south.29.002 | st.south.29.003  |
    +---+------------------+-----------------+------------------+
```

It's the text in between st,nt, and the 00~s that's the key to this, but I'm not sure how to go about this at all.

May I ask for someone's help with this please?

Comment: This will need VBA, *I think*

Comment: I agree with urdearboy, I am pretty sure you will need VBA to accomplish this, or a very, very long IF formula.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I wanted to know if anyone could point in me a specific direction. I've been googling stuff, but I haven't been able to find THAT article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for your data set.  It's a fairly simply implementation so you'll need to adjust for what you need.

You'll need to create a new worksheet called **Output** in order for it to work.

You'll also need to add a reference in your VBA project to **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** to make it work (here's hoping you're not on a Mac).

Simply select your data range and watch it go.

```
Public Sub DoTranspose()
    Dim objValues As Scripting.Dictionary, objSrcCells As Range, objCell As Range
    Dim strKey As String, strValue As String, arrValues() As String, varKey As Variant
    Dim lngWriteRow As Long, lngWriteCol As Long, i As Long, objDestSheet As Worksheet

    Set objValues = New Scripting.Dictionary

    ' Use a new sheet called "Output" for the results.
    Set objDestSheet = Sheets("Output")

    ' Simply use the selected set of cells as the data for the transposition.
    Set objSrcCells = Selection

    For Each objCell In objSrcCells
        strValue = objCell.Value
        strKey = UCase(Left(strValue, Len(strValue) - 3))

        If Not objValues.Exists(strKey) Then
            ' The key doesn't exist, therefore, add it and add the first value.
            ReDim arrValues(0)
            arrValues(0) = strValue

            objValues.Add strKey, arrValues
        Else
            ' The key exists, append to the values array.
            arrValues = objValues.Item(strKey)

            ReDim Preserve arrValues(UBound(arrValues) + 1)
            arrValues(UBound(arrValues)) = strValue

            objValues.Item(strKey) = arrValues
        End If
    Next

    lngWriteCol = 0

    objDestSheet.Cells.Clear

    ' Write the results of the dictionary out to the destination sheet.
    For Each varKey In objValues.Keys
        lngWriteRow = 0
        lngWriteCol = lngWriteCol + 1

        arrValues = objValues.Item(varKey)

        For i = 0 To UBound(arrValues)
            lngWriteRow = lngWriteRow + 1
            objDestSheet.Cells(lngWriteRow, lngWriteCol) = arrValues(i)
        Next            
    Next

    objDestSheet.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Ahhhhhh, maybe :-) Depends what you want to chat about. Can you enlighten me on here first?

Comment: I tried using your sub. I'm not as pro in VBA so I'm a little unsure as to how to approach the part where you say to use Microsoft Scripting Runtime. I don't want to get banned for being too dumb -.-'.

Comment: @ChunkyFresh don’t worry, you won’t get banned. Try this ... https://itstillworks.com/add-scripting-runtime-type-library-7495029.html

Comment: I was able to run it. Unfortunately, it just kept transposing all of the data to one row instead of segregating it to multiple rows based on their similarities.  Now that I'm reading your answer closely and with more understanding, I guess you meant  it was on me to add within what you provided something that does transpose based on criteria.

Comment: The important part will be the key that it derives which is the line ... strKey = UCase(Left(strValue, Len(strValue) - 3)) ... that's essentially getting everything except the last 3 characters and that's what defines the key.  So the key for ... "nt.north.35.001" ... will be ... "nt.north.35." ... and that's what's used to perform the grouping, does that make sense?

Comment: oooooooooooohhh.... ok let me try that! I forget that the solutions given are in context to what I offered in my example.

Comment: If it doesn't work, give me an example of a set of values that you're wanting to group so I can see what will need to change to make it work.